# strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

i want to make time slot between the start time and end time and show the disponibility of the user but i get this error :   strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

this is the controller :

```
$model=doc::findOrFail($ID);
$ReturnArray = array ();// Define output
$StartTime    = strtotime ($model->Lun_mat_de) ; //Get Timestamp
$EndTime      = strtotime ($model->Lun_mat_a); //Get Timestamp
$duration = '60';

$AddMins  = $duration * 15;

 //Run loop
while ($StartTime <= $EndTime) {
    $ReturnArray[] = date ("G:i", $StartTime);
    $StartTime += $AddMins; //Endtime check
}

return view ('/rendezvous',['go'=> $model],['jaja'=>$ReturnArray] );
```

this is the view :

```
<div class="div1" ></div>
 @foreach($jaja as $ja)
     <button class="btn btn-info"> {{$ja}} </button> </br>
 @endforeach
```

this is the model :

```
  protected  $table = 'doctor' ;

       protected $casts = [
        'Lun_mat_de' =>'array',
        'Lun_apres_a' =>'array',
        ];
```

Comment: what does `print_r($model->Lun_mat_de)` show?

Comment: ["8:30","12h30"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value `$model->Lun_mat_de` is an [array variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) type rather than a string, as expected.

## From Comments:

> - what does print_r($model->Lun_mat_de) show?
> - `["8:30","12h30"]`
> - Right, that is an array, which of these values do you want to be turned into a time value?
> - Lun_mat_de' and 'Lun_mat_a'
> - No, You have told me that `$model->Lun_mat_de` gives you an array of two values, you need to choose which of these two values you want the [PHP function `strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to work on. 8:30 or 12h30?
> - oh sorry yes `8:30`

Ok,
So to get the `strtotime` function to work on `8:30` you would put:

```
$StartTime    = strtotime ($model->Lun_mat_de[0]); //8:30
```

To get the `strtotime` function to work on the other value, the `12h30` then you would reference the other array value:

```
$StartTime    = strtotime ($model->Lun_mat_de[1]); //12h30
```

(*I assume here the array is integer keyed*)

## Recommended Reading:

Please read the PHP Manual entry on [**`array`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), [**`string`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) types as well as the function [**`strtotime`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Also you should actually probably be using the [**`DateTime` function**](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/class.datetime.php) going forward.

Answer (score -1):

You defined in you model casts `Lun_mat_de => array` so $model->Lun_mat_de always returns you an array. so `strtotime ($model->Lun_mat_de)` will crash. fix the casts field

Comment: This doesn't actually help with solving the problem, this simply clarifies what the problem is, which is pretty obvious already